# SQLite highscores with 3 columns - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to implement a method that is making my head spin with all the if-elseif-else and while loops.  I have a SQLite db with 3 columns -- autoincrement, score(long) and percentage(int).  The percentage comes from the correctness of 10 questions and the score is going to be some number calculated between 0 and 1000.  So there will be a lot of ties in percentages and (probably) none in the scores.

The high scores is ranked first by the percentage and then to "break the tie" of all the records with the same percentage value, it is then ranked by score.  Did all that make sense?  If not, let me know and I will edit and try to explain it better.

My question is if anyone has any suggestions or other examples I could follow to get this method done.  Also, is it okay with how I am doing it?  I am inserting into the table with a `rawQuery()` instead of using my `insert()` method because I need to insert at a specific index most of the time into my db.  I have included my insert method as well.

```
//Check if new record makes the top 10.
public int check(long score, int percentage) {
    Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE, null);
    Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE, null);
    if(c1 != null && c2 != null) {
        int i = 0;
        while(c1.moveToNext() == true) {
            int ii = 0;
            c1.moveToPosition(i);
            do {
                int x = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("PERCENTAGE"));
                if(x > percentage) {
                    db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "VALUES (" + i + ", " + score + ", " + percentage + ");", null);
                } else if (x < percentage ) {
                    i++;
                } else {
                    int y = c2.getInt(c2.getColumnIndex("SCORE"));
                    while(x == percentage) {
                        //ahhhh!





                    }
                        if(y > score) {
                            db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "VALUES (" + i + ", " + score + ", " + percentage + ");", null);
                        } else
                    if(c2.getCount() == 10) {
                        //Delete last record in high score and insert at index.
                        delete(10);
                        //db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + RANK + " = 10;", null);
                        db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "VALUES (" + i + ", " + score + ", " + percentage + ");", null);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        //No deletion - just insert.
                        db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "VALUES (" + i + ", " + score + ", " + percentage + ");", null);
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } while (c2.moveToNext());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

insert()

```
//Insert new record.
public long insert(long score, int percentage) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SCORE, score);
    values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);

    return db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
}
```

Comment: If the score is between 0..1000 and percentages, by definition are between 0..100, why don't you make it easy on yourself and just calculate ranking = percentage * 1001 + score, then sort by ranking?

Comment: Oh wow, I did not think of that.  That is why I stopped and asked this question - I knew there had to be an easier way.  Thanks @323go!